# Android canvas drawText - how to bottom align text?

Tags: android, android-canvas, drawtext

I have a custom View which is supposed to draw some text bottom aligned.
Size of text should be 50% of view height.

How should I change this code to work correctly?

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    float h = getMeasuredHeight();
    float textHeight = h*0.5f;
    paint.setTextSize(textHeight);
    String str = "Abcdefghijklm";

    paint.getTextBounds(str, 0, str.length(), bounds);
    float height = bounds.height();
    float yPos = height;
    canvas.drawText(str, 0, yPos, paint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your yPos to:

```
float yPos = getHeight() - bounds.getHeight();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16568536)

Comment: This is the answer bro, notice that i provided a working code to replace in her own code